# Closing a port listening on a local host

Tags: centos, sudo, netstat, port

How do i close a port listening on a local host in CentOS7? 
So far I have used the below command to find the process id

```
sudo netstat -tlpn | grep 5601
```

Then, used the below command to kill the process but it starts up with new process id.

```
sudo kill -SIGTERM 29565
```

Please help.

[image]

Comment: Please post text as text. Not as an image. It will make it easier to read (especially for blind people).

Comment: What is the executable running in that process? Same for its parent?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the Unix & Linux StackExchange!

Your picture indicates that when you kill the process currently occupying the port with SIGTERM, a new process will take its place. So either `systemd` is configured to automatically restart the process whenever it gets killed, or the process holding the port is just a "worker" child process of a major server application.

The name of the process in question seems to be `node` according to your `netstat -tlpn` output. So, I'd try first to check if there are system services named like that:

```
systemctl | grep -i node
```

Once the exact name of the service is known (e.g. `node.service`), you can stop the service with this command:

```
systemctl stop node.service
```

and if it turned out to be the wrong thing, restart with

```
systemctl start node.service
```

Once you've confirmed that you've stopped the correct service, you might want to disable the service so that it won't be started automatically at the next system reboot:

```
systemctl disable node.service
```

Answer (score 1):

To search for processes that listen on a specific port, use the lsof or “List Open Files”.

```
lsof
```

Find Processes running on Specific Port
The `-i` option to filter

```
lsof -i TCP:[PORT]

lsof -i TCP:5601
```

Kill all Processes listening on Specific Port
The `-t` command returns only the PID, precisely for piping, and use `xargs` on each line returned.

```
lsof -ti tcp:[PORT] | xargs kill

lsof -ti tcp:5601 | xargs kill
```

If the process is more persistent, and kill did not work, try `kill -9 [PID]` to kill it more aggressively.

**References**

[Find (and kill) all processes listing on a port](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/e4c8c665a8-find-and-kill-all-processes-listening-on-a-port)

[10 lsof Command Examples in Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/10-lsof-command-examples-in-linux/)

Comment: This here is the same approach I use. I have the following in my bash_profile: `function kpt(){ lsof -ti ":$1" | xargs kill; }`. Usage `kpt 5000` (kpt <port number>).